# Node.js deploy - AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

ey guys.

I'm just starting to learn how to deploy a node js application using AWS Elastic Beanstalk and I got stuck in this part from the [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.sdlc.html):

```
From the directory where you created your local repository, type the following command:

eb start

Once the environment status is Green, AWS Elastic Beanstalk will output a URL for the application
```

At the end of the process, I got:

```
INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: Successful: 0, Failed: 1.
```

And no URL returned.

In the web panel I have the following in the log entries:

```
ERROR   Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation
```

What might have happened? I'm a beginner with AWS technologies and I'm totally lost! Here are the last 100 lines log: http://pastebin.com/r2wDUP1L

It seems it crashed while trying to npm install express... Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, the problem was that GIT wasn't installed.

I was able to install git using Amazon ebextensions to manage the required packages to deploy and then just `git aws.push`. Everything worked out!

Comment: git aws.push is no longer avaiable in the EB Command line. I am constantly running into this error, do you have any advice?

Comment: @andrewoodleyjr I recommend you to generate a log and see where the error might come from. In my case it was GIT, but it may be something completely different for you.

Comment: Thanks, I found the issue. It was the port number (correct to 8081) and properly updating the git commit ( use git commit -a -m '' ). Afterwards I uploaded with eb deploy and it worked.